# Alternative for ADDRESS function that returns an array

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, libreoffice-calc

I primarily use LibreOffice Calc instead of Excel. When creating my spreadsheet, I relied upon the fact that the `ADDRESS` function was able to take a cell range and return an array of cell reference strings. But this doesn't work in Excel as the function doesn't work on arrays.

I have a table of values from which I want to sum selected columns in a row. The columns to select is named cell range `mycols` and the row is `myrow`, giving the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(myrow, mycols)))
```

For example:

- `ADDRESS` returns `{$A$2, $D$2, $B$2}` with `myrow=2` and `mycols={1,4,2}` (but only `$A$2` in Excel).
- `INDIRECT` returns the cell values `{1,2,3}`.
- `SUMPRODUCT` returns `6` in LibreOffice, but `1` in Excel.

I tried using the `RC` notation instead and concatenating arrays, but concatenation isn't note element-wise so this doesn't work. I'd like not to use macros.

Comment: Assuming `myCols` = `={1,4,2}`  and not the string `{1,4,2}`: In Excel 2010, try entering this as an array formula by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.  In more recent versions of Excel with dynamic arrays, you can use `=ADDRESS(myRow,myCols#)`

Comment: I'd like to have it in a single formula, no temporary cells, as each cell of another large table contain this formula. `ADDRESS` has the same result with ctrl+shift+enter. I'd also like to maintain compatibility and LibreOffice doesn't seem to support dynamic arrays.

Comment: The problem is with the `ADDRESS` function. If the `ADDRESS` formula in Excel 2010 still only returns the single value with `ctrl+shift+enter`, I cannot help you with an Excel formula solution. I do not have 2010 on my system so cannot test anything. Hopefully another will have a solution that works for you that does not involve upgrading all of your Excel installations.

Comment: Welcome! Nicolas, your story is incomplete. If you know the row number and the required columns, why don't you just write `=SUM(A1;D1;B1)` ? Tell us in more detail why you chose such a complex and unreliable method, what is the reason for such an approach to extracting values from a table. I wanted to suggest something like `=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($A$1:$D$40;myrow;mycols))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET($A$1;myrow-1;mycols-1))` , but a quick check showed that Excel does not process such constructions correctly ...

Comment: The row and column are the results of another formula, they aren't constant. It seems neither `INDEX` or `OFFSET` work in the way I want, returning an array given an array of columns.

Comment: And you do not want to write a user-defined function in VBA?

Comment: If it's the only option I'll go with it, it seems LibreOffice has some support for VBA.